# How to open Google spreadsheet with specific sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are 31 sheets which have name of date, like "1Day", "2Day",...., "31Day".

And I want to go to **today's date sheet** automatically when I open spreadsheet.
Do you know how to do?
(It's not allowable to change the name of sheet so.... the sheet name have to be "1Day", "2Day",...)

I think maybe triggers are useful but wonder how to write code before using the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var today = new Date().getDate();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.find(s => parseInt(s.getName()) == today).activate();
}
```

It activates the sheet that that has the same number in its name as current date whenever you open or reload the spreadsheet.